# Удаление строки из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим есть в бд есть структура id name desc
На страницу выводятся все записи из бд таким образом:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from items;");
while($news = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
    echo "<div class=block>".$news['name']."-".$news['desc'];
  }
```

Как мне сделать чтобы выводилась кнопочка удаления, и удалалясь та строка, на которой и было совершено действие удаления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Добавить ссылку на удаление по ID
echo '<div class="block">'.$author['name'].'-'.$author['desk'].'<a href="?delete_author="'.$author['id'].'">Удалить</a>';
//Запрос используя метод GET
$query = mysql_query("delete from items where id = '".$_GET['delete_author']."';");
```

Comment: ну как минимум проинтовать это все дело    `(int)$_GET['delete_author']` при удалении

Comment: ну про (int) и прочие проверки мы обычно умалчиваем, должен же человек сам понять что пишет и по безопасности сам немного шевелится в лучшую сторону.

Comment: Не нужна звездочка, буде ошибка sql запроса кагбы ;D

Comment: точно) пардон, копировал просто строку из вопроса)

Answer (score 1):

Удаление обычной ссылкой по GET-у почти всегда плохая идея, т.к. на эту ссылку может "нажать" любой робот, даже поисковик от яндекса. Даже если ее нет на странице.
Безопаснее это делать так:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="b6f78544ce4327ac66737bef5f951292"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="del_id" id="del_id" value="<?php echo $author['id'];?>">
<a onclick="if (confirm('Вы уверены, что хотите удалить <?php echo $author['name'];?>')) {this.parentNode.submit();}; return false;">Удалить</a>
</form>
```

CSRF-token используется для защиты от CSRF-атак, подробнее [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Прием сообщения на удаление:

```
<?php
if (strtoint($_POST['del_id'])) {
    $query = mysql_query("delete * from items where id = '".$_POST['del_id']."';");
    ...
};
?>
```

Comment: Но только если это используется в Админке, зачем делать такие жесткие проверки? ИМХО .

Answer (score 0):

передавай id items кнопке и удаляй по id